# Client/server setup with network login and standard system image?

Tags: image, thin-client

In my school library, I notice that everytime I log in to a client computer, the system seems to load my preferences and settings from a server, and the client seems to run some sort of static system image which is then personalised with my settings.

This seems really useful for the admins, since they can install the same image on all client computers. Users don't have permissions to actually make local changes. Yet personalisation is still possible...

What is this concept called? What components are required?

Thanks.

Comment: Please read the FAQ. This question is off-topic.

Comment: @ErikA Sorry, what would be a better place for a question like this? Superuser?

Comment: Actually, talking to the IT department of your school would probably be the best. Depending on how busy they are, they may even offer to give you a tour of their IT infrastructure. At the very least, it could be the start of a relationship with a group of people who are always good to have on your side. :)

Comment: OK. Thanks for your answers despite me asking in the wrong place!

Answer (score 2):

Roaming profile, combined with restricted admin rights, managed using Active Directory and Group Policy.

Requirements are: Windows AD domain, Windows Clients, a file server to hold the profiles, and enough know-how to wire everything together.

Comment: Of course, for all we know, it could be WinTerms and Citrix servers with something like FlexProfile. Or Novell ZenWorks and NDS (or AD.)